# Ошибка автоматического запуска chromedriver'а

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Несколько дней назад по необъяснимым мне пока причинам фоновая работа selenium'а (через Xvfb) стала сопровождаться автоматическим запуском экземпляра chromedriver'а.
Выглядят эти процесса вида

```
/home/chromedriver --port=12328 --log-path=/var/log/selenium-chrome.log
/home/chromedriver --port=20727 --log-path=/var/log/selenium-chrome.log
/home/chromedriver --port=28574 --log-path=/var/log/selenium-chrome.log
```

И так далее. Каждый из них пытается запустить при этом экземпляр chrome'а, что в сумме приводит к очень высокой нагрузке на сервер.

Сам скрипт запуска выглядит следующим образом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DISPLAY=:1 xvfb-run -a java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="/home/chromedriver" -Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile="/var/log/selenium-chrome.log" /home/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

Обновление chromedriver'а и самого chrome'а ни к чему не привели.